# jQuery fade out when scrolling: element flickers on viewport border

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm having this code:

The .fade elements have opacity=0. I'm adding the class 'visible' when the elements reach the viewport and remove the class after leaving it. So far everything runs fine, but the elements show a weird flickering when reaching the upper viewport border: they disappear, come back and disappear again, as if they're not sure whether they’re on or off the viewport. This is my jQuery and CSS:

```js
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  var tags = $(".fade");
  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
   var tag = tags[i];
   if(isScrolledIntoView($(tag))){
    $(tag).addClass("visible");
   }
   else {
    $(tag).removeClass("visible");
   }
  }
 });
 function isScrolledIntoView(elem){
  var $elem = $(elem);
  var $window = $(window);
  var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();
  var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();
  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
 }
```

```css
.panel { 
  height: 500px; 
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.p1 { background: red; }
.p2 { background: green; }
.p3 { background: orange; }
.p4 { background: green; }

.fade {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 2.0rem;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0); 
}

.fade.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1.0s;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='panel p1'>
<div class='fade'>Content Fade 1</div>
</div>

<div class='panel p2'>
<div class='fade'>Content Fade 2</div>
</div>

<div class='panel p3'>
<div class='fade'>Content Fade 3</div>
</div>

<div class='panel p4'>
<div class='fade'>Content Fade 4</div>
</div>
```

The slower you scroll, the more obvious gets the problem. I would prefer to remove the class not before the element is fully out of viewport, maybe even plus a little extra space.

Any hint that helps me beating this tricky little devil is more than welcome.

Thanks
Ralf

Comment: Please don't post your executable code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Just place that code into a code snippet, right here. Also, don't place "part" of executable code into a code snippet, so that that part is no longer executable. Code snippets are to run code in. If you just want to show some code, don't place it in a snippet.

Comment: I am not experiencing the issue you describe when running in Chrome 74 on Windows 10.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you very much. I didn’t know how to do it, it’s absolute fine how you edited for me.

Comment: I'm not having a windows machine at the moment, but the issue shows up on MacOs Firefox, Chrome and Safari all in the exact same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit :- I have added the code snippet to properly do this. You had already achieved most of the goal, just left a little bug around, you see you cannot observe the element moving out of the viewport and move it back in kinda defeats the purpose, what you can do is put another div as the placeholder for the default visible position of div you're trying to hide/display and observe that div. The snippet and it's code will show you it.

P.S :- If you noticed the observe word a lot, try looking into the intersection observer to achieve this kind of functionality without doing all these calculations which are prone to errors. They are not 100% browser compliant but just look at you audience, also the snippet provided works and I've tested it.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var tags = $(".fade");
    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        var tag = tags[i];
        if(isScrolledIntoView($(tag).siblings(".fade-check"))){
            $(tag).addClass("visible");
        }
        else {
            $(tag).removeClass("visible");
        }
    }
});
function isScrolledIntoView(elem){
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var $window = $(window);
    var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();
    var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();
    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

```css
.panel { 
    height: 500px; 
    position: relative;
    color: white;
}

.p1 { background: red; }
.p2 { background: green; }
.p3 { background: orange; }
.p4 { background: green; }

.fade {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    max-width: 500px;
    padding: 2.0rem;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0); 
    transition: all 1.0s;
}
.fade-check {
    padding: 2.0rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 1rem;
}
.fade.visible {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class='panel p1'>
        <div class='fade-check'></div>
        <div class='fade'>Content Fade 1</div>
    </div>

    <div class='panel p2'>
        <div class='fade-check'></div>
        <div class='fade'>Content Fade 2</div>
    </div>

    <div class='panel p3'>
        <div class='fade-check'></div>
        <div class='fade'>Content Fade 3</div>
    </div>

    <div class='panel p4'>
        <div class='fade-check'></div>
        <div class='fade'>Content Fade 4</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is a happening because you are relying on the offset value of the .fade elements to determine whether or not they have been scrolled up or not and if they are. You are applying translate on them, which is changing the offset result, which is why you get that wobbling effect, simply remove the `translate: transform(-50%, -50%)` from the fade.visible element and move the transition into the .fade class and you will get the fade in effect you desire.

Comment: Thanks Himanshu, I tried your suggestion and now it happens what I suspected: The wobbling is gone, but unfortunately the .fade elements are not moving anymore but just fading. Perhaps I didn’t make that clear enough: I’d like them to have two transitions – to fade in and to slightly move to their final position centered in .panel. I’m not suprised that the problem had something to do with the offset, but how can I achieve to run both transitions? Or is is not possible?

Comment: My apologies Ralf. I got the idea that you were just trying to fade them out from the title of the post. I have updated the answer and included the snippet to do what you were asking for. Please let me know if this solves your problem, please also consider acknowledging the answer if it solves your problem, and looking into the intersection observer api, there is also a polyfill available for it now.

Comment: Perfectly done, Himanshu, a million thanks! And no reason to apologize – it was me that didn't make my plan clear enough.